# Differentiation of Logarithm Map in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a simple question regarding the differentiation of the logarithm mapping in Riemannian manifolds:

Assume that $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $p(t), q(t): [0,1] \to M$ be two curves.

I am interested in bounding the quantity

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\log_{p(t)}(q(t)),
$$

more precisely, does the estimate
$$
\left|\frac{d}{dt}\log_{p(t)}(q(t))\right|\lesssim \left|\frac{d}{dt}p(t) - \frac{d}{dt}q(t)\right| 
+ \left|p(t) - q(t)\right|
$$
hold true, at least if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are close to each other??

Comment: 1) Why do you need to isometrically embed the manifold into $\mathbb{R}^n$? 2) Your question is best posed in terms of Jacobi fields. I think if you take the trouble to do that, you might be able to figure out whether your inequality or something like it holds.

Comment: thanks for your comment.

1) because otherwise the right hand side would not make sense.

2) thanks for the suggestion of using Jacobi fields. I tried it and die not see whether the inequality holds...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?